# Rails update product quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, callback, checkout

I followed Ryan Bates screencasts using paypal standard payments and i basically now have to send checkout info from the Cart model.
I'm a bit stuck with trying to update product quantity after the transaction is completed.

I tried using a callback but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated

The closest i got was to use this update quantity callback but for some reason, it is updating the wrong cart. Not sure whether it picks up the wrong line item or its when it checks the cart it goes wrong

```
 class PaymentNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :cart
   serialize :params
   after_create :mark_cart_as_purchased, :update_quantity


private

def mark_cart_as_purchased
  if status == "Completed"
    cart.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now)
  end
end

def update_quantity
  @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
  @line_item.upd
end
end
```

Line Item Class

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :stock
  after_create :stock_stat 


   def total_price
     product.price * quantity
   end

   def upd
     if cart.purchased_at
       product.decrement!(quantity: params[:quantity])
      end
    end

 end
```

Comment: How is params getting into LineItems?

Comment: @ken I was trying to find the LineItem using id?

Comment: @ken I thought using the callback could pass the params

Comment: In your udp function, I don't see how it is getting the params variable.

Comment: @ken do i need to find LineItems again in the "upd" method?

Comment: No, but you are using params there: `product.decrement!(quantity: params[:quantity])`

Comment: @ken I'm using  `product.decrement!(quantity: params[:quantity])` because LineItem `belongs_to :product`

Comment: But you aren't passing `params` to the method.

Comment: @ken how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The params hash is only available in the controller. You cannot access it in the model. You have to pass params[:quantity] to the upd method as a method parameter as such:

```
def update_quantity
  @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
  @line_item.upd(params[:quantity])
end

def upd(quantity)
  if cart.purchased_at
    product.decrement!(quantity: quantity)
  end
end
```

Also, you should consider using Time.current instead of Time.now in order to account for the time zone your application is configured with in application.rb unless you just want to use whatever time is local.